# SQL Server Table Transformation Query / Combine Column Names With Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my existing SQL Table with 3 columns (q1, q2, q3) and 2 rows :

```
> q1 q2 q3
> --------
> 1  2  3
> 4  5  6
```

I need an SQL query that would transform that table and return a result set containing 2 new columns (cg, sg) and 6 rows combining table column names with values:

```
> cg  sg
> ======
> q1  1
> q1  4
> q2  2
> q2  5
> q3  3
> q3  6
```

Perhaps that would require some kind of "PIVOT" operation, but I can't get it to work after numerous tries.

Any advice or solution? Thanks.

PS I can't use stored procedures, only a single query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another method that scans the table only once.

```
SELECT
   x.*
FROM tbl t
CROSS APPLY( VALUES
    ('q1', q1),
    ('q2', q2),
    ('q3', q3)
) x(cg, sg)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using UNION:

```
SELECT 'q1' as cg, q1 as sg FROM t1
UNION SELECT 'q2' as cg, q2 as sg FROM t1
UNION SELECT 'q3' as cg, q3 as sg FROM t1
```

Comment: Elegant and smart, thanks a lot! A small remark for real data sets (which I found out while testing) is that you can use UNION ALL to get all the values - and not only the distinct ones.

Comment: UNION ALL is also faster, because it doesn't need to build and check a DISTINCT list